# Django get_model method tries to get Django's Flatpages application instead of my Flatpages application

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, django-flatpages

I have overrided the Django's Flatpages application and write my own Flatpages application. Django Oscar project is importing Flatpage Model with get_model method.

```
FlatPage = get_model('flatpages', 'FlatPage')
```

when i run development server

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

it imports my Flatpage application 
but when i use uwsgi-nginx server it imports Django's own flatpage application.

It is also same, importing Django's Flatpage when i do not use nginx and use gunciorn.

```
gunicorn dhr.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:80
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely a path issue. Add a debugging statement that prints out the result of `os.getcwd()` and `sys.path`. Try making your path under uwsgi / gunicorn more similar to development.